# How to return a list in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Let me first start by saying that I am not good at programming yet. I have the following exercise:

Define a function which iterates the Ricker model a total of 600 times for a particular value of ***a***. The arguments of the function should be the parameter ***a*** and the initial condition ***x0***. Your procedure should return a list (for example, `mylist`) that contains the coordinates for the points that will appear in the Feigenbaum diagram. Note that you do not create coordinates for the first 500 iterates, only for last 100 iterates. Hint: Each coordinate in the list should be of the form `[a,iter]` not `[i,iter]`. Make sure your program returns the values in the list.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function y = ex824(a)
    RM      = @(x) a*x.*exp(-x);
    prompt  = 'Specify an initial condition: ';
    result  = input(prompt);
    iter(1) = result;

% collecting list of x-coordinates
    for i = 1:601,   
        X(i) = i - 1;
    end

% collecting list of y-coordinates
    for i = 1:600,
        Y(i+1)      = RM(iter(i));
        iter(i+1)   = Y(i+1);
    end

    y = plot(X, Y, '*');
end
```

I have a couple of matlab programming books, but I've been reading for days and have yet to come across something that shows me how to return a list. Can anyone help?

Comment: Comparing your title with your question reveals same major differences. Please remove all the unnecessary blabla from your assignment and focus on your question. We won't do your homework anyway for you.

Comment: I find your comment to be rude and unnecessary. I wasn't asking anyone to do my homework for me. You have read that nowhere in my question. My title says EXACTLY what I wanted help with. I don't know how to return a list... My unnecessary blabla, as you call it, is there to show that I have attempted the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I did not meant to be rude. For me your question has to much text and code unrelated to the actual question. A good question tries to be general and precise.

Comment: Understood. I'll be sure to keep my future questions precise.

Comment: Do you specifically want a list? In general matlab works with vectors and matrices. I would recommend to use a matlab vector instead.

Comment: @patrik, now that you've mentioned it, I think that's what they meant by list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to generate a list and assign this to your return variable.

```
function a = testReturnList(size)
  a = ones(size, 1);
  %a = [1;2;3];
end
```